# I just got to know him last year

Tags: grammar, american-english, phrase-usage, periods

"I just got to know him." If I'm not wrong this sentence means, I recently meet him?

If that's the case, what does "I just got to know him last year" mean? One year is a long time, so what does this actually mean?

Comment: I would say that what comprises a long time is subjective. For the speaker it is not a long time. I won't post an answer since I have a hunch that this question will be put on hold.

Comment: I'm 70 years old.  "Last year" could mean as recently as 6 months ago.  That's not a "long time" to me.

Comment: "I just got to know him last year" looks like it's direct speech. It could be a case where an adjustment is made in speaking, to either add more information or to sharpen / correct content. "I just got to know him ... last year" makes this clearer, but indicates a noticeable pause for thought which may not have been what actually happened. //  It's unlikely that this 'just' indicates 'I just managed to' (before he left for Mars, etc).

Comment: @HotLicks ...and you don't sound a day over 60!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - "He's been my neighbor since 1983 but I just got to know him last year" would be perfectly sensible speech.

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes, another 'just' – the 'unexpectedly late in the scheme of things' just, not the 'just about made it' just. Just how many senses does the thing have? // I put 'to either' followed by another 'to-clause' in my first comment. Why can't we correct them?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Shirley you just.

Comment: *Got to know him* also doesn't necessarily mean *met him*. You could know somebody by sight at work, and pass them in the office every couple of months, even have said hello to them from time to time, but not *get to know* them for years or decades—when you actually go out for a meal or drinks and exchange personal information.

Answer (score 1):

"just" has several meanings. One of them is "recently", but when combined with other adverbials of time "just" can mean -- as I think is the case here -- "only". Imagine this conversation:

A: Tell me more about your neighbor.

B: Well, I don't know him very well. Actually, I just got to know him last year. (= I got to know him only last year.)

Comment: I see. Thank you guys very much.